# How to schedule a function in Flask App daily at every 5 minutes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I would like to know how the `check` function can be executed everyday at 5 minutes interval.

```
import time
from flask import Flask

def check():
    print(time.time())


app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Update**

I tried the below but nothing happended.

```
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import AndTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger


trigger = AndTrigger([IntervalTrigger(minutes=5),
                      CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri)])
scheduler.add_job(job_function, trigger)
```

Comment: hi @Akhil i wrote a possible answer to your question before you recently made an update which make my answer obsolete and not fit your updated concern so it may be subject to down votes from anyone reading your question. i kindly suggest you add little description or simply insert the word "UPDATE" before the newly added part. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you need to schedule a `Cron` job with `Crontab` if you are planing to deploy your `Flask` app on `unix-like` server. for `windows` server i have no clue how to do that but for sure you can plan tasks.

try `python-crontab` [package](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) if you need to manipulate dynamically your `crontab`, it's **not mandatory** for your case if you have the needed permissions on hosting server to insert an entry in `user crontab file`

few resources that may help you affording this

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
- https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/ (tutorial about the `python-crontab`)
- https://medium.com/@gavinwiener/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e

you need a separate and standalone python script apart from your `Flask` app since `cron` can't execute a remote http request like curl / wget only shell/python/.. scripts, commands .., meaning in your case you can't insert `https://myflaskapp.dev/check` in crontab like

```
5 * * * * https://myflaskapp.dev/check
```

but the work around is that your `cron` job execute standalone python script which send/execute an http request to that endpoint like :

```
5 * * * * /home/webapps/www/myflaskapp.dev/check.py
```

in `check.py` you can put simple python script using `requests` library that just make an http request (get,post ..) depending on your logic in `check` function

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 
  
# endpoint 
URL = "http://myflaskapp.dev/check"

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API (Optionnal)
PARAMS = {'param1': param1}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS) 

[...]
```